# Dynamically populating wordrpess shortcode from an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to customize output of wordpress smart grid plugin. My aim is to add list of images into a section and output them through the plugin. The image list has to be wrapped by the plugin shortcode. Which I have done, only problem is looping. Here is my code

```
            <div class="p_details_right">
                <?php 
                  //print_r($partner_pictures); 
                  $pic_bucket = [];  //empty array to hold list of image id to be used within the wordpress default gallery shortcode
                ?>
                <?php 
                        foreach ($partner_pictures as $key => $item) { 
                        array_push($pic_bucket, $key); // populating the array which holds image id
                ?>                            
                <?php 
                } 
                        //print_r($pic_bucket);
                ?>
                <?php echo do_shortcode("
                        [smart-grid]
                            [gallery ids='$pic_bucket[0],$pic_bucket[1],$pic_bucket[2]']   // <----- PROBLEM . Currently doing it statically but I need to be able to add populate the id element of the shortcode dynamically based on the $pic_bucket array.
                        [/smart-grid]
                "); ?>
            </div>
```

Currently outputting the gallery by statically adding array element but I need to be able to add populate the id element of the shortcode dynamically based on the $pic_bucket array. Tried to do looping but does not work. I am missing something very basic.

### Sollution

convert Array to string and assign ids variable with that.

```
            <div class="p_details_right">
                <?php 
                  //print_r($partner_pictures); 
                  $pic_bucket = [];  
                ?>
                <?php 
                        foreach ($partner_pictures as $key => $item) { 
                        array_push($pic_bucket, $key);
                ?>                            
                <?php 
                } 
                        //print_r($pic_bucket);

                        $str = implode(',',$pic_bucket);
                ?>
                <?php echo do_shortcode("
                        [smart-grid]
                            [gallery ids='$str']
                        [/smart-grid]
                "); ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: `[gallery ids=' . implode(',',$pic_bucket)` would help?

Comment: yes, This worked. Thanks. As I said, missed the basic bit :D

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, don't update the question and add "solved" in the title.

Comment: @deceze wanted to do that, but immediately stack didn't allow me to post as answer. I didn't want people to keep putting comment to something already solved as a result edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join an array of ID's together with `implode(',',$array)`